# Live Looping using an iPad, MIDI Keyboard and laptop

Tags: ableton-live

I’m hoping to set up a virtual loop station using an iPad and the Quantiloop app.

I’ve got the Arturia KeyLab MK2 connected via USB to a MacBook. I’ve then been connecting the Mac to an amp using aux when playing live.

What I’d like to do is record live loops from the iPad while playing the keyboard. I use Analog Lab generally but do have the sounds plugged into Ableton Live (Lite) and Logic.

I’m not sure how to cable this up. I’m guessing:

MIDI Keyboard - Laptop - iPad - Amp,

but would I get away with connecting the laptop to the iPad via USB? I’ll need the sounds generated by Analog Lab to pass to the iPad. If anyone could offer some advice I’d really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance for any help.